# Rails 3 - Return the id of each nested attribute that was created

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3

Is there anyway for me to return the id's of the nested attributes when they are created?

right now i return the id of the parent this way. Where @report.id is the parent.

```
format.json { render :json => { :success => true, :report_id => @report.id } }
```

I would like to do something like this....

```
format.json { render :json => { :success => true, :report_id => @report.id, :the_ids_for_the_created_nested_attributes => @report.icons.ids } }
```

Comment: Please show some (condensed) code of your issue where you highlight what you currently have and want to achieve. Right now, your question is very vague.

Comment: When I create a nested attribute, is there anyway for me to return the id of the nested attribute that was created?

Comment: I'm not sure how you could get the ones just created. But to get all of them would be: `@report.icons.collect { |i| i.id }`

Comment: Credit to agmcleod and rails docs

Create and array in the respond_to for the create action in the controller, collect the icons loop through and put the id for each icon in the array. return the array.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Credit to agmcleod and rails docs

Answer: Just put @report.icons in the response, then parse the json.

```
format.json { render :json => { :success => true, :report_id => @report.id, :report_icons => @report.icons } }
```

Answer (score 0):

To get the ones that were just created, keep the ones that existed before the edit, and take the difference.

And names like "the_ids_for_the_created_nested_attributes", particularly in an example, would probably be better expressed as something like "icon_ids", if for no other reason than we don't have to scroll as much to see what you really meant.